# .OBJ: Is there any way, that the number of vertexes of a face is changing?

Tags: 3d, file-format

The question belong to the *.obj files (3D).

Is it possible, that faces contain 3 vertexes and later in the file 4 ?

Comment: It's a widely used and misused format, so you can assume that there's objs out there that mix tris and quads. The question is, do you want to load all the objs in the world? Unlikely, so test it with the exporters of the programs that you expect to load them from.

Comment: If you want to go by the original spec it only says "A minimum of three vertices are required". There's no real upper limit, it could be a 50-sided polygon and still be a valid *.obj.

Comment: Okay, I was worrying about the "mixing". I am currently coding a .obj loader and it was unclear, if I should add a "mixed" support. Thank you for your help !